# "Depends on" relationship for subclasses

Tags: uml

I have a few questions about UML:

1. If a class (let's call it *B*) is derived from *A*, and the class *A* uses some other other classes (has relationship), do I have to draw the arrows also from *B* to all used classes?
2. If a class uses an `ArrayList<myclass>`, is correct to say that this class uses `myclass`?
3. If a method uses generics (or templates), what syntax do I adopt for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. The properties are inherited implicitly, no need to model them explicitly again.
2. Yes, if you mean that the ArrayList contains only member of myclass - just draw an to-n association to myclass.
3. You can use UML templates for parameterization. It looks like [this](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Parameterized+Class/). But don't use it for collections - using to-n associations (like in 2) is better.